# Import data from Website: Converting Java Script code into VBA code

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, dom

I need to import some data from [this website](http://chem.sis.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/rn/112-92-5), for which I have written a small java script code which is mentioned below.

**Code for extracting Molecular Weight**

```
x = document.getElementById('summary')
y = x.getElementsByTagName('h2')
count = x.getElementsByTagName('h2').length
flag=0
for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
  if(y.item(i).textContent == 'Molecular Weight'){
    console.log(y.item(i).nextSibling.textContent);
   flag=1;
  }
}
if(flag==0)
console.log("Nothing Found");
```

**Code for extracting data from physical properties table**

```
x=document.getElementById('physical')
y=x.getElementsByClassName('TableRow')
count =x.getElementsByClassName('TableRow').length
for(i=0;i<count;i++){
   z=x.getElementsByClassName('TableRow').item(i)
   z.children[0].textContent
   z.children[1].textContent
}
```

So Is it possible to import to excel through java script?

I think VBA will be better for this purpose but I am new to VBA and not able to identify the appropriate way to write the code in VBA.
Please give me hint so that I can proceed in right direction.

Comment: You would probably be best served with an xmlHTTP object but your ultimate goal(s) is/are unclear. You have provided javascript functions to retrieve values from a single and specific HTML page format. That is provided for you below.

Comment: My question may be little bit unclear  but what I want is to pick the last part of url from excel cells like `111-92-5` will be replaced by some another string (specifically called `RN number`) which will open a new and unique page for each `RN number`. My ultimate aim is to extract data (only `Molecular weight` and `Physical properties` as described in question) from each page and store that in excel sheet. From table I need to extract first 2 columns of each row.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing through javascript, you might want to try the following. In excel you can import a website into a spreadsheet by going to `File -> Open Url`. Assuming the structure of the site is the same regardless of the molecule you are looking at you could create VBA script to extract the data just by looking at the cell address. You can use `Tools -> Macro -> Record New Macro` to record your actions. Then once done you can view the VBA code by going to `Tools -> Visual Basic Editor`. Then you can improve the code from there to further automate the process.

Here is an example:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://chem.sis.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/rn/112-92-5"
Range("A44").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("B4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: This is one web page if I change the `111-92-5` in address, a different page with different structure might appear and in that case your method will not work. You can change above address to `http://chem.sis.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/rn/61789-40-0`

Comment: Why you want to first import all the data to excel and then picking up some specific elements ? Don't you think It's much difficult and time consuming process?

Comment: I see you really want to crawl a set of pages on this site. You could use [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/) with node.js(https://nodejs.org/) to crawl all the pages you want utilizing your javascript code to extract the data you want. Then save the data into csv format so that it can be opened in excel